# Newton-Raphson Division With Big Integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer, division, bigint

I'm making a BigInt class as a programming exercise. It uses a vector of 2's complement signed ints in base-65536 (so that 32-bit multiplications don't overflow. I will increase the base once I get it fully working).

All of the basic math operations are coded, with one problem: division is *painfully* slow with the basic algorithm I was able to create. (It kind of works like binary division for each digit of the quotient... I'm not going to post it unless someone wants to see it....)

Instead of my slow algorithm, I want to use Newton-Raphson to find the (shifted) reciprocal and then multiply (and shift). I think I have my head around the basics: you give the formula **(x1 = x0(2 - x0 * divisor))** a good initial guess, and then after some amount of iterations, x converges to the reciprocal. This part seems easy enough... but I am running into some problems when trying to apply this formula to big integers:

**Problem 1:**

Because I am working with integers... well... I can't use fractions. This seems to cause x to always diverge (x0 * divisor must be <2 it seems?). My intuition tells me there should be some modification to the equation that would allow it to work integers (to some accuracy) but I am really struggling to find out what it is. (My lack of math skills are beating me up here....) I think I need to find some equivalent equation where instead of **d** there is **d*[base^somePower]**? Can there be some equation like **(x1 = x0(2 - x0 * d))** that works with whole numbers?

**Problem 2:**

When I use Newton's formula to find the reciprocal of some numbers, the result ends up being just a small faction below what the answer should be... ex. when trying to find reciprocal of 4 (in decimal):

```
x0 = 0.3
x1 = 0.24
x2 = 0.2496
x3 = 0.24999936
x4 = 0.2499999999983616
x5 = 0.24999999999999999999998926258176
```

If I were representing numbers in base-10, I would want a result of 25 (and to remember to right shift product by 2). With some reciprocals such as 1/3, you can simply truncate the result after you know you have enough accuracy. But how can I pull out the correct reciprocal from the above result?

Sorry if this is all too vague or if I'm asking for too much. I looked through Wikipedia and all of the research papers I could find on Google, but I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall. I appreciate any help anyone can give me!

...

Edit: Got the algorithm working, although it is much slower than I expected. I actually lost a lot of speed compared to my old algorithm, even on numbers with thousands of digits... I'm still missing something. It's not a problem with multiplication, which is very fast. (I am indeed using Karatsuba's algorithm).

For anyone interested, here is my current iteration of the Newton-Raphson algorithm:

```
bigint operator/(const bigint& lhs, const bigint& rhs) {
    if (rhs == 0) throw overflow_error("Divide by zero exception");
    bigint dividend = lhs;
    bigint divisor = rhs;

    bool negative = 0;
    if (dividend < 0) {
        negative = !negative;
        dividend.invert();
    }
    if (divisor < 0) {
        negative = !negative;
        divisor.invert();
    }

    int k = dividend.numBits() + divisor.numBits();
    bigint pow2 = 1;
    pow2 <<= k + 1;

    bigint x = dividend - divisor;
    bigint lastx = 0;
    bigint lastlastx = 0;
    while (1) {
        x = (x * (pow2 - x * divisor)) >> k;
        if (x == lastx || x == lastlastx) break;
        lastlastx = lastx;
        lastx = x;
    }
    bigint quotient = dividend * x >> k;
    if (dividend - (quotient * divisor) >= divisor) quotient++;
    if (negative)quotient.invert();
    return quotient;
}
```

And here is my (really ugly) old algorithm that is faster:

```
bigint operator/(const bigint& lhs, const bigint & rhs) {
    if (rhs == 0) throw overflow_error("Divide by zero exception");
    bigint dividend = lhs;
    bigint divisor = rhs;

    bool negative = 0;
    if (dividend < 0) {
        negative = !negative;
        dividend.invert();
    }
    if (divisor < 0) {
        negative = !negative;
        divisor.invert();
    }

    bigint remainder = 0;
    bigint quotient = 0;
    while (dividend.value.size() > 0) {
        remainder.value.insert(remainder.value.begin(), dividend.value.at(dividend.value.size() - 1));
        remainder.value.push_back(0);
        remainder.unPad();
        dividend.value.pop_back();

        if (divisor > remainder) {
            quotient.value.push_back(0);
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            int i = MSB;
            bigint value = 0;
            while (i > 0) {
                bigint increase = divisor * i;
                bigint next = value + increase;
                if (next <= remainder) {
                    value = next;
                    count += i;
                }
                i >>= 1;
            }
            quotient.value.push_back(count);
            remainder -= value;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < quotient.value.size() / 2; i++) {
        int swap = quotient.value.at(i);
        quotient.value.at(i) = quotient.value.at((quotient.value.size() - 1) - i);
        quotient.value.at(quotient.value.size() - 1 - i) = swap;
    }

    if (negative)quotient.invert();
    quotient.unPad();
    return quotient;
}
```

Comment: [your solution returns `1` instead of `2` for `2/1`](https://ideone.com/cGNsdl)¶ You think you found a solution, you could [post it as your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (answers should be posted as answers, not question updates).

Comment: Here's a [working (in my tests) `unsigned_div_newton()` implementation in Python (text in Russian)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/788422/23044). The implementation based on long division (`unsigned_div_long()`) is much faster for cases I've tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you can implement division in time `O(n^2)` and with reasonable constant, so it's not (much) slower than the naive multiplication. However, if you use [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm)-like algorithm, or even [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm)-based multiplication algorithm, then you indeed can speedup your division algorithm using Newton-Raphson.

A Newton-Raphson iteration for calculating the reciprocal of `x` is `q[n+1]=q[n]*(2-q[n]*x)`.

Suppose we want to calculate `floor(2^k/B)` where `B` is a positive integer. WLOG, `B≤2^k`; otherwise, the quotient is `0`. The Newton-Raphson iteration for `x=B/2^k` yields `q[n+1]=q[n]*(2-q[n]*B/2^k)`. we can rearrange it as

`q[n+1]=q[n]*(2^(k+1)-q[n]*B) >> k`

Each iteration of this kind requires only integer multiplications and bit shifts. Does it converge to `floor(2^k/B)`? Not necessarily. However, in the worst case, it eventually alternates between `floor(2^k/B)` and `ceiling(2^k/B)` (Prove it!). So you can use some not-so-clever test to see if you are in this case, and extract `floor(2^k/B)`. (this "not-so-clever test" should be alot faster than the multiplications in each iteration; However, it will be nice to optimize this thing).

Indeed, calculating `floor(2^k/B)` suffices in order to calculate `floor(A/B)` for any positive integers `A,B`. Take `k` such that `A*B≤2^k`, and verify `floor(A/B)=A*ceiling(2^k/B) >> k`.

Lastly, a simple but important optimization for this approach is to truncate multiplications (i.e. calculate only the higher bits of the product) in the early iterations of the Newton-Raphson method. The reason to do so, is that the results of the early iterations are far from the quotient, and it doesn't matter to perform them inaccurately. (Refine this argument and show that if you do this thing appropriately, you can divide two `≤n`-bit integers in time `O(M(2n))`, assuming you can multiply two `≤k`-bit integers in time `M(k)`, and `M(x)` is an increasing convex function).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helped me to create a _working_ N-R division algorithm. Unfortunately, after all this trouble my old algorithm is still (much) faster! There's a good chance that I'm not using a good number for the initial guess. Also the truncation optimization you were talking about is probably crucial for efficiency. I'm still working out how to use it. Otherwise, if nothing else, I do think I got something practical out of this: I should be able to use this algorithm to speed up my toDecimalString() function,which uses repeated divisions. I will update my question with my code.

Comment: what does q[n+1] mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I see this correctly a major improvement is picking a good starting value for x. Knowing how many digits the divisor has you know where the most significant bit of the inverse has to be, as

```
1/x = pow(2,log2(1/x))
1/x = pow(2,-log2(x))
1/x >= pow(2,-floor(log2(x)))
```

floor(log2(x)) simply is the index of the most significant bit set.

As suggested in the comment by the op using a 256-bit lookup table is a going to speed up the convergence even more, because each step roughly doubles the amount of correct digits. Starting with 8 correct digits is better than starting with 1 and much better than starting with even less than that.

```
  constexpr fixpoint_integer_inverse(const T& d) {
    uint8_t lut[256] = { 255u,254u,253u,252u,251u,250u,249u,248u,247u,246u,245u,244u,243u,242u,241u,
240u,240u,239u,238u,237u,236u,235u,234u,234u,233u,232u,231u,230u,229u,229u,228u,
227u,226u,225u,225u,224u,223u,222u,222u,221u,220u,219u,219u,218u,217u,217u,216u,
215u,214u,214u,213u,212u,212u,211u,210u,210u,209u,208u,208u,207u,206u,206u,205u,
204u,204u,203u,202u,202u,201u,201u,200u,199u,199u,198u,197u,197u,196u,196u,195u,
195u,194u,193u,193u,192u,192u,191u,191u,190u,189u,189u,188u,188u,187u,187u,186u,
186u,185u,185u,184u,184u,183u,183u,182u,182u,181u,181u,180u,180u,179u,179u,178u,
178u,177u,177u,176u,176u,175u,175u,174u,174u,173u,173u,172u,172u,172u,171u,171u,
170u,170u,169u,169u,168u,168u,168u,167u,167u,166u,166u,165u,165u,165u,164u,164u,
163u,163u,163u,162u,162u,161u,161u,161u,160u,160u,159u,159u,159u,158u,158u,157u,
157u,157u,156u,156u,156u,155u,155u,154u,154u,154u,153u,153u,153u,152u,152u,152u,
151u,151u,151u,150u,150u,149u,149u,149u,148u,148u,148u,147u,147u,147u,146u,146u,
146u,145u,145u,145u,144u,144u,144u,144u,143u,143u,143u,142u,142u,142u,141u,141u,
141u,140u,140u,140u,140u,139u,139u,139u,138u,138u,138u,137u,137u,137u,137u,136u,
136u,136u,135u,135u,135u,135u,134u,134u,134u,134u,133u,133u,133u,132u,132u,132u,
132u,131u,131u,131u,131u,130u,130u,130u,130u,129u,129u,129u,129u,128u,128u,128u,
127u
    };
    const auto l = log2(d);
    T x;
    if (l<8) {
      x = T(1)<<(digits(d)-1-l);
    } else {
      if (digits(d)>(l+8)) x = T(lut[(d>>(l-8))-256])<<(digits(d)-l-8);
      else x = T(lut[(d>>(l-8))-256])>>(l+8-digits(d));
    }
    if (x==0) x=1;
    while(true) {
      const auto lm = long_mul(x,T(1)-x*d);
      const T i = get<0>(lm);
      if (i) x+=i;
      else return x;
    }
    return x;
  }

  // calculate a * b = r0r1
  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value,tuple<T,T>>::type
  constexpr long_mul(const T& a, const T& b){
    const T N  = digits<T>()/2;
    const T t0 = (a>>N)*(b>>N);
    const T t1 = ((a<<N)>>N)*(b>>N);
    const T t2 = (a>>N)*((b<<N)>>N);
    const T t3 = ((a<<N)>>N)*((b<<N)>>N);
    const T t4 = t3+(t1<<N);
    const T r1 = t4+(t2<<N);
    const T r0 = (r1<t4)+(t4<t3)+(t1>>N)+(t2>>N)+t0;
    return {r0,r1};
  }
```

Comment: The answer came way late, but Lykos nailed it: the starting point. Newton-Raphson doubles the amount of precision at each step, but if you have a bad starting point, you'll spend a long time getting up to a reasonable amount of precision.

Let's say you wanted to compute 1/3, and your first guess was 0.5.  The NR sequence would be 0.5, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.33203125, 0.3333282470703125, 0.33333333325572312, 0.3333333333333333

But if you had a 256-element lookup table, you get the first 8 bits right on iteration 1, and start with 0.33203125; you'd only need 3 iterations rather than 6.

Answer (score 0):

Newton-Raphson is an approximation algorithm - not appropriate for use in integer math.  You will get rounding errors which will result in the kind of problems you are seeing.  You could do the problem with floating point numbers and then see if you get an integer, precise to a specified number of digits (see next paragraph)

As to the second problem, pick a precision (number of decimal places) you want for accuracy and round to that precision. If you picked twenty digits of precision in the problem, you would round to 0.25.  You simply need to iterate until your required digits of precision are stable.  In general, representing irrational numbers on a computer often introduces imprecision.

Comment: Newton-Raphson can be adapted to be very useful in discrete, exact calculations.  For one good discussion of the details, see Gathen, Gerhard, Modern Computer Algebra, Third Edition, Chapter 9 : Newton Iteration.